# How do we know that group representations exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Given a finite group $G$, how do we know that there exists a map $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ such that $\rho(g_1\circ g_2) = \rho(g_1).\rho(g_2)$ for any $g_1, g_2\in G$?

Intuitively, why does matrix multiplication always capture the properties of a group?

Comment: If you know about Cayley's theorem/permutation representation of a group, you can always make permutations act linearly on a vector space. There's one way.

Comment: This is a bit vague.  There's always the trivial representation, say.  If $G$ is finite, then $G$ injects into a symmetric group, and any finite symmetric group injects into some $GL(V)$.  Or were you thinking of something else?

Comment: First of all, who is claiming that we do know this? Second, the trivial map always works, so we do know this (but it is a pretty uninteresting thing to know)

Comment: In particular, because of Cayley's theorem, and the identification of $S_n$ with the set of permutation matrices on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you know that there is an injective map $\rho$. You can construct this directly (although its the same as Cayley's theorem) : consider the vector space with basis elements $1_h$ labelled by $h \in G$, and have $G$ act on this by $g \cdot 1_h = 1_{gh}$, and extending the action linearly.

Comment: @lulu sorry for the vagueness. I am bascially learning group theory from scratch (I did a course many years ago but have forgotten pretty much all of it). The lecture I used (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhTGyDuNI_w) starts off with this. I guess the trivial representation is not very useful but perhaps your comment about injection into the symmetric group is what I was trying to understand.

Comment: For finite groups, that's the easiest way to exhibit a faithful representation, that is, an injective homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$.  Is it clear that, say, $S_n$ injects into $GL_n(\mathbb C)$, say?

Comment: Having looked through the start of that video, I don't see this claim anywhere. He simply defines a representation as a thing that satisfies these conditions.

Comment: @lulu it is not yet to me but I now know what to read up. Thank you.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, you are right. That was an assumption on my part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permutation matrices fully capture the essential features of the symmetric groups. So for $S_n$ I would take all of the $n!$ permutation matrices of size $n \times n$ and this allows me to ensure any finite group can be represented by matrices this way. Since all groups are subgroups of symmetric groups this allows us to realize the group structure for an arbitrary finite group.

This is however almost never the minimal representation so while it ensures existence we're typically interested in finding the lowest possible dimensional representation, not an arbitrary one. You can see this immediately as $S_3$ only requires a two dimensional representation being isomorphic to $D_6$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be any finite group. We can form a free vector space on the group $G$ by $k[G]$. That is, we define a basis $\{e_g\}_{g\in G}$. Now, we can define a linear action of $G$ on $k[G]$ by left translation. That is, let $g\in G$ act on the left by $g\cdot e_h=e_{gh}$ for all $g,h\in G$. We extend this by linearity to a linear map $T_g:k[G]\to k[G]$. It is not hard to see that $g\mapsto T_g$ defines a group homomorphism $G\to \text{GL}(k[G])$.

Indeed, $T_g\circ T_{g'}(e_h)=e_{gg'h}=T_{gg'}(e_h).$ This formula also shows that $T_{g^{-1}}=T_g^{-1}$ so that the $T_g$ are linear isomorphisms.

Comment: To help OP recognize the used vector space: Note $k$ here is any field (e.g. $k=\mathbb R$) and $k[G]$ is just $k^G$, which is the set of maps $G\to k$ with addition $(\varphi+\psi)(g) = \varphi(g)+\psi(g)$ and scalar multiplication $(\lambda\cdot \varphi)(g) = \lambda\cdot\varphi(g)$. This in turn is isomorphic to $k^n$ for $n=|G|$ by any choice of enumerating the elements of $G$.